# Truncate the table in scylla - loading back.

Tags: cassandra, cql, scylla

I am trying to truncate a table in scylla which is a three node cluster. But immediately data is loading back, some times truncate working fine, which means I can able to delete the data not table schema using the following command, but some times data is loading back.

```
truncate table students ;
```

I tried to explore scylla and Cassandra documentations, they mentioned some thing because of tombstone filter this ghost replication happening, but my cluster tombstone grace period is default. So it should delete the data before tombstone expires. Anyone please help me why it is happening and what is the solution for this not to happen.

Answer (score 4):

If truncate returned success (IOW, didn't fail or caused any exception), then your data should be gone. One explanation for what happened in your case is that the operation wasn't successful in some of the nodes. Truncate in this case should have returned a failure.

If it didn't return any failure and the data is still there, this is likely a malfunction and you should report that to the Scylla team in their bug tracker

Comment: Yes operation is successful and data still remains. Some times not working but sometimes working fine. It might be the malfunction. Thank you.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/3694. Does that look like your case?

Comment: @SureshKumar according to the github issue, trying multiple times makes it eventually succeed. If you have more information on how to reproduce I am sure the Scylla team would love to work with you to fix it

Comment: For me also same like eventually get succeed. But some times truncate happening in a single attempt. 
I tried to reach them but I have not got any source to contact them.

Comment: Same like github issue for me also truncate happening eventually. But sometimes it is working in a single shot. I don't know what is happening in the Scylla cluster.
I already tried to reach the Scylla team, but I have not got any source to contact them. If you know anything please help me to contact them..